# "Internal graphics redirecting card" for motherboard with no video port?

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, intel-graphics

The motherboard in my PC has no video port on it. (Model: GA-P61-USB3-B3)

My CPU (i7-2600) has its own internal graphics, but as motherboard doesn't have a video port so I am using an external video card (GTX 560) to make monitors work.

If the video card gets broken or somewhat unavailable, is there any "internal graphics redirecting card" or "additional video port" that I can replace it with, or should I have to buy a new video card?

Comment: @Ramhound - Does that mean I should replace the motherboard by one with video port on it?

Comment: You can do anything you want.  You cannot use the Intel iGPU without a video port on your motherboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If the video card gets broken or somewhat unavailable, is there any
>   "internal graphics redirecting card" or "additional video port" that I
>   can replace it with, or should I have to buy a new video card?

The only way to use the `Intel® HD Graphics 2000` is to upgrade a motherboard that has a video port.  It might be helpful to know, the `Intel® HD Graphics 2000` integrated GPU (iGPU) is absolutely abysmal.

> Is it physically unreachable (e.g. M/B has no part to communicate with
>   internal graphics so it can't redirect signals to PCI-e) or just
>   because there is no such board?

`Intel® HD Graphics 2000` is integrated into your i7-2600.  It cannot be used unless you install the CPU into a motherboard which has a video port.

Comment: Thanks for helping, then it seems I should consider a new video card for next PC...

Comment: If you current external GPU is working you have no reason to replace it.